# Unable to locate element in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to input username on username input field using Selenium C# but it throw no such element: Unable to locate element.

Here is what I have tried but non of them worked.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("demo@zigzy.com");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("demo@zigzy.com");
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id='username']")).SendKeys("demo@zigzy.com");
```

Below is the HTML I am trying to access

```
<form class="form" data-id="username-password-validator-form">
    <div class="float-label placeholder-shown" data-id="username-input">
        <input class="text-input float-label__input branding-template-text-input" data-id="username-input-input" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" autocomplete="on" value="">
        <label class="float-label__label" for="username">Username</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the element is in an IFRAME?

Comment: Agree with @JeffC. Check if an iframe exist. If its not a sensitive information share the URL you are trying to automate.

Answer (score -2):

This problem may come from variety of causes. Firstly, you may want to re-check if the element is existed or not. Secondly, the website you are trying to use selenium is blocked by Developer. Thirdly, you may get stuck at the login page.

Comment: It is a login page which trying to do automation. As checked the website not an iFrame.